# Why is date order by not supported in window functions in hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

In the table, a user can have rows on multiple dates. And the objective is to get the first row (defined by date) of each user. I try the following sample query, which throws an error saying the date type is not supported.

Query:

```
select user_id, first_value(f0) over(partition by user_id order by activation_date asc) from  table limit 10
```

Error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies.
Underlying error: Primitve type DATE not supported in Value Boundary expression
```

The query works using timestamp(activation_date). Coming from a BigQuery background, I use date quite frequently and think it is a very useful feature. Is there a reason why order by date (in window functions) is not supported in hive?